# Asymptotic behaviour of quantity related to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Consider the differential equation

$$u''(t) + u(t) + u^3(t) = f(t) u(t) + g(t),\,\, u(0) = u_0, \,u'(0) = u_1$$

where $u :\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded solution  and $f, g: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ are given continuous functions such that $$\lim_{t\to \infty} f(t) = \lim_{t\to \infty} g(t) = 0.$$
Define the quantity $E(t) := \frac 12 (u(t))^2 +\frac 12 (u'(t))^2 + \frac 14 (u(t))^4.$
I want to study the asymptotic of $E$ when $t \to \infty.$  First, I considered many examples for $f, g$ using mathematica (See the attached images where I plotted $t\mapsto E(t)$). I'm interested in the case where
$\liminf_{t\to \infty}E(t) >0$ or roughly $\lim_{t\to \infty} E(t) >0.$ I wonder if this is the general case or it depends on the initial values $u_0, u_1$ and $f,g.$ In all the examples that I tested numerically, I found that $\lim_{t\to \infty} E(t) >0.$
My attempt started by differentiating $E$ with respect to $t.$ It seems that in the case where
$u'$ is bounded, we have $$\lim_{t\to \infty} E'(t) =0,$$
since $E' = (f u + g) u'.$ But this does not imply necessarily that $\lim_{t\to \infty}E(t) >0.$
The limit might be zero.

Thank you for any hint.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. Is it physics related or pure maths?

Comment: Mathematical physics :D

Comment: You can certainly kill a carefully chosen solution by $f,g$. Just put $g=u^3$. Then all you need is to kill $u$ in the equation $u''+u=fu$. Now just take that harmonic oscillator and apply some decaying force against the motion when it is far from the origin (as long as it deviates a certain distance, you can keep the force fixed, so the energy is lost at a fixed rate). That will send everything to $0$ at $+\infty$

Comment: @fedja Do you mean that I just need to consider the harmonic oscillator with some decaying force $F,$ so that $u'' + u = F$? In that case and when coming back to the OP, $f$ will be $F/u.$ How can you chose $F$ such that $\lim_{t\ to \infty} f(t) = 0$? 
I'd be grateful if you give more explicit details about the decaying force in the harmonic oscillator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the system to be well-behaved a sufficient condition is that $f$ and $g$ are integrable at infinity.

Consider some uniform bounds of the RHS in terms of the energy functional (a standard trick): The $f$ term behaves the best. By Cauchy-Schwarz you have $|uu'|\leq E$ whereas for the $g$ term you only have $|u'|\leq \sqrt{2 E}$. We thus get the crude bound:
$$ |E'| \leq |f| E + |g| \sqrt{2E}$$.

A special case is $g\equiv 0$ for which we get (use e.g. a Gronwall Lemma):
$$ |\log(E(\infty)) - \log(E(0)) | \leq \int_0^\infty |f(t)|dt.$$
In this case it suffices that $f$ is integrable in order for
$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}  E(t)$ to exist and be strictly positive.

When $g$ does not vanish you may put e.g. $E=\frac12 A^2$  which yields (as long as $A>0$):
$$ |A'| \leq \frac12 |f| A + |g| $$

When e.g. $f$ and $g$ are integrable then also in this case the  system never explodes (use again a Gronwall Lemma) and will have a finite limit  which, however, may be zero. You may also from this get conditions on initial values of $A$ which when large enough compared to the $L^1$ norm of $f,g$ give lower bounds that assures that the limit is strictly positive. For example, a sufficient condition is that
$$ A(0) \ (1 - \frac12 \|f\|_1) > \|g\|_1 $$

Comment: Thank you very much for this adequate answer. Under the same assumptions that you mentioned above (integrability of $f,g$), I was thinking of proving that $u$ converges to $v$ the solution of  $v'' + v + v^3=0$ but for unknown initial values.

Comment: You are welcome.  In the $(u,u')$ plane the solution is winding around and you would need to show that the perturbation only yields a finite 'phase'-shift when integrated forward in time (to infinity). This looks quite plausible.

Comment: It yields a finite phase shift and a change in the  "amplitude."

Comment: OK, looks reasonable and promising. Is this part of your research or just for fun?

Comment: Somehow a part of my research. It's a bit related to specific topic in the domain of semi linear wave equations. If you are interested, I'd be happy to send you more details and work together on it. I guess you are affiliated to a place where I did a part of my undergraduate edu. and worked as well :).

Comment: You are welcome to send me details. I like the problem. And yes, I am easy to find. All the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117924/discussion-between-a-pi-and-h-h-rugh).

Answer (score 2):

If $\;t\to\infty,\;$ then the given ODE takes the form of
$$\ddot u+u+u^3 =0,\tag1$$
which does not contain variable $\;t.\;$

Substitution $\;P=\dot u,\;\ddot u = P'_u\, \dot u = P\,\dfrac{\text dP}{\text du},\;$ presents $(1)$ in the form of
$$P\,\text dP = -(u^3+u)\,\text du,$$
$$P=\dfrac12\sqrt{(a^2+1)^2-(u^2+1)^2},$$
$$\dfrac{\text du}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}} = \sqrt{2+a^2+u^2},\tag2$$
and after substitutiion
$$v=\arcsin \dfrac ua$$
one can get
$$\text dv = \sqrt{2+a^2(1+\sin^2 v)}\,\text dt,$$
with the [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dv%2Fdt%3Dsqrt%282%2Ba%5E2%281%2B%20sin%5E2v%29%29)
$$v(t) = \text{am}\left(\sqrt{a^2+2}\,(t+b)\bigg|\dfrac{a^2}{2+a^2}\right)$$
[and](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%20sin%28am%28sqrt%28a%5E2%20%2B%202%29%20%28t%2Bb%29%2C%20-a%5E2%2F%28a%5E2%20%2B%202%29%29%29)
$$u(t) = a \text{ sn}\left(\sqrt{a^2+2}\,(t+b)\bigg|\dfrac{a^2}{2+a^2}\right),\tag3$$
where $\;\text{am}\;$ and $\;\text{sn}\;$ are the Jacobi functions.

The Jacobi functions looks too heavy for applying of the constant variations method.

Taking in account derivatives
\begin{cases}
\left(\text{sn}(x|m)\right)' = \text{cn}(x|m)\text{ dn}(x|m)\\[4pt]
\left(\text{cn}(x|m)\right)' = -\text{sn}(x|m)\text{ dn}(x|m)\\[4pt]
\left(\text{dn}(x|m)\right)' = -m\text{ sn}(x|m)\text{ cn}(x|m),
\end{cases}

looks possible to find parameters $\;a\;$ and $\;b\;$ for the given functions $\;f(t)\;$ and $\;g(t)\;$ numerically, using the next statement:

- $E(t) = \dfrac14(2u'^2+u^4+2u^2) \ge 0,$
- $E(0) = \dfrac14(2u_1^2+u_0^4+2u_0^2),$
- $E'(\infty) = 0,$
- $E(\infty) = E(0)+\int\limits_0^\infty(uf+g)\,\text dt.$

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer to solve the limit equation (mentioned (1)). But still have some remarks/questions: Equation (1) is non linear and the right hand side of the original equation has $u$ as well. So how can you apply the "constant variation" method ? 
In which sense the original ODE tends to (1)? 
How can the proposed solution in your answer be useful to study the asymptotic of E when $t \to \infty$ ?

Comment: @A.PI Since $f(t)\to 0$ and $g(t)\to 0$ when $t\to\infty,$ then $(1)$ is the asymptotic case for the bounded solutions of the given ODE. On the other hand, the quantity $E$ contains only the derivative and the degrees of $u.$ At the same time, consideration of b  as the certain function looks as non-suitable way.

Comment: This means that the left hand side of the original equation tends to that of (1), but not necessarily for the solutions.  Check numerically  the example where $f(x) = g(x) = e^{-x}$  with initial values $u_0 = u_1 =0.$ It is clear that the corresponding unique solution for  equation (1) is $u =0.$ However, the original ODE seems to have nontrivial solution that doesn't tend to 0 when $t \to \infty$

Comment: @A.PI You are right, thanks! Fixed typo.

Comment: After many numerical tests for different examples of $f, g,$ It seems that the solution to the original ODE tends to a function of type (3) but with different values of $a, b$ than for (1).

Comment: @A.PI Thank you  for the comments! I'm glad that it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117782/discussion-between-a-pi-and-yuri-negometyanov).

Comment: In fact, numerical tests are not a proof. What I wanted to say is that the solution to the original ODE behaves asymptotically when $t\to \infty$ as a solution of (1) but with "mysterious" initial values. This is still a conjecture.

Comment: @A.PI We can get E(t) and provide the conditions of OP via a and b values. This does not look misterious.

Comment: At this level you can not get any information about the asymptotic of $E(t)$ when $t\to \infty.$ Whereas, in the case of Equation (1) in your answer this quantity is clearly constant.

Answer (score 0):

*I'd be grateful if you give more explicit details about the decaying force in the harmonic oscillator*

You can do it as I said or you can do it in an even simpler way and put $f=0$, $g=u^3-u'$ (effectively eliminating the non-linear term and adding the damping). Then you just have a linear equation $u''+u'+u=0$, which has an exponentially decaying solution, so your $g$, indeed, tends to $0$ at infinity. The more interesting question seems to be

*Is there any pair $f,g$ tending to $0$ at $\infty$ such that *all* (or, at least, many) solutions decay to $0$ at infinity?*

though, perhaps, I'm missing something simple here.